# How to fill the gap while scale

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-transitions

How can fill the gap at the bottom while using `-webkit-transform:`?

There is a gap when `div` becoming small. How can I fix this gap?

[image]

Here is the code

```
<div id="popUp">
    <div id="trans">
        <h1>hover me</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#popUp{
    height: auto;
    width:400px;
    background: #EEE;    
}
#trans{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background: yellow;

    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;

    -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0;
       -moz-transform-origin: left top 0;
         -o-transform-origin: left top 0;
        -ms-transform-origin: left top 0;
            transform-origin: left top 0;
}
#trans:hover{
    -moz-transform: scale(.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(.5);
    -o-transform: scale(.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    transform: scale(.5)
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/XpJEQ/3/**

I couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: What gap are you referring to?

Comment: same question. What gap are you referring to?

Comment: @ralph.m and HaBo give me 1 min please. Let me upload screen shot

Comment: @HaBo please let me know if you didn't understand when look the image

Comment: To clarify, the OP wants the text below the yellow box to remain flush to the bottom of the box even when it's animated to half it's size using `scale(.5)`

Comment: @Bojangles the dive `#popUp` height is auto. I need the function like dive becoming small automatically `#popUp` height become small . something like that.  Hope you understand my question

Answer (score 5):

The only solution I can think of would be to remove the element from the DOM flow (set it's parent to `position: relative`, then absolutely position the element) and animate the `padding-top` of the subsequent element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XpJEQ/7/

CSS (minus vendor prefixes):

```
#popUp {
    background: #EEE;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
#trans {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    transform-origin: left top 0;
}
#trans:hover { transform: scale(.5); }
#trans + * {
    padding-top: 210px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#trans:hover + * { padding-top: 110px; }
h1 { text-align: center; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="popUp">
    <div id="trans">
        <h1>hover me</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I've slightly modified your initial code as following (there is no gap between text and yellow rectangle on transform):

```
#popUp{
    height: 300px;
    width:400px;
    background: #EEE;

    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;

    -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0;
     -moz-transform-origin: left top 0;
     -o-transform-origin: left top 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: left top 0;
      transform-origin: left top 0;
}
#popUp:hover{
    -moz-transform: scale(.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(.5);
    -o-transform: scale(.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    transform: scale(.5)
}
#trans{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background: yellow;
 }

h1{
    text-align: center;
}
```

It fits the initial requirements of eliminating that gap. If there are any additional requirements, then the code can be modified, correspondingly.

Comment: This `scale`s everything, and not just the yellow `div`.

Comment: @Alex Bell Thanks for your help but actually these function I am using for graph on popup. Your solution effecting all the contents of the popup

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 `transform` `scale2d` will not cause repositioning of elements around it. If you want the text to move, you would need to change the actual `height` and `width` of the element.